# npm run watch fails to run, but gives no error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-run

I am working on a project with a couple of others using laravel and react/material ui.
Something happened to my npm (someone tried to fix it and ran npm audit fix --force) and therefore I needed to reinstall it. I deleted npm, deleted node js, reinstalled node js and ran npm install.

I have tried countless things so far, including things like remove node modules and package-lock.json and using rm node_modules and rm package-lock.json followed by npm cache clear --force.

When I run something like npm run watch or npm run dev this is the output I get.

```
> watch
> npm run development -- --watch


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
```

After that I expect it to compile and stuff but instead I see the line
SP C:\xampp\htdocs\projectName
I have tried it with xampp running and without xampp, I also tried it from the phpstorm terminal and the cmd (with admin rights) but sadly nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find in the end was reïnstalling Windows. There probably was something like a node or npm folder left somewhere that was interfering with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, another `npm run watch` was running in background from another launch

killing it solved